# PHP $_REQUEST returns NULL from Query

Tags: php, jquery

Hi I'm supposed to make a search function for school in PHP but the keywords never reach the PHP code.

index.hmtl

```
<div role="search">
<img class="posirel" src="smallm.png" alt="smallm">
<input id="search" onclick="showAlert()" class="chnginput" type="text" name="suchparam" value="" placeholder="Suche" onkeyup="javascript: showhint(this.value)">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search posirel" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<select id="searcher"></select>
<div id="srchbox"></div>
</div>
```

main.js

```
function showhint(query) {
    if (query.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById("srchbox").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        $.get("ajax.php?query=" + query) .then(function (r) {
            document.getElementById("searcher").innerHTML = r;
        });
    }
}
```

ajax.php

```
$q = $_REQUEST["query"];
$hint = array();

echo  "<pre>" ;
var_dump($q);
print $q;
echo  "<pre>" ;
```

The keyword reaches the JQuery Code but I've have no Idea how to go on from here.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Thanks but still doesn't work

Comment: So if you open your developer tools (usually F12) and go to the network tab, then make the ajax request happen, you don't see the query being passed with your value?  Edit: You do have a space before your `.then()` so that may be a syntax error.  Fix that too.

Comment: Alright I've delete the Space and the output from the network is:

GET /ajax.php?query=g 

But I Still get only NULL

Comment: Where do you get NULL?

Comment: either from the print $q; or the var_dump($q);

Comment: So maybe a dumb question on my part, but why don't you echo that?  Why the switch between methods of writing output?

Comment: Because I'm a complete newby to php and I read on w3schools that both of them are the same I just choose it because i usually write in C

Comment: So lets try this.  Try doing just the following in your ajax.php and see what you get: `echo $_REQUEST["query"];`  Because from what you said you saw in the network request, that 'query' key is being sent

Comment: When I do this I only get an empty document

Comment: What if you use `$_GET['query']` instead of `$_REQUEST['query']`? What would be the output?

Comment: same result 

an empty Document

Comment: Check in your network tab if the value is coming back on the response there.  If it is, then I'd point to the answer below mentioning that you are trying to put a non option value inside a select element, which may be why the data is not rendering.  If so `document.getElementById("searcher").innerHTML = '<option>'+ r +'</option>';` might fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple of issues - firstly you are trying to write content into a `select` element in the ajax callback function but the PHP code is not generating content suitable for that purpose. Also, as noted there is a space before the `.then(` portion of the code.

In the code below I edited the url so it is all in one script to demo the result and used a standard div to display output rather than the `select`. You'll notice I used `$_GET` rather than `$_REQUEST` - you can use either but when pages get more complicated it makes sense to use either `$_GET` or `$_POST` rather than `$_REQUEST` to avoid collisions with requests.

```
<?php

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET' && !empty( $_GET['query'] ) ){
        ob_clean();

        print_r($_GET);

        exit();
    }

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Basic jQuery Ajax search</title>
        <script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js'></script>
        <script>
            var showAlert=function(){

            }
            function showhint(query) {
                if (query.length == 0) {
                    document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = "";
                    return;
                } else {/* change url here to ajax.php */
                    $.get( "?query=" + query ).then(function(r) {
                        document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = r;
                    });
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div role="search">
            <img class="posirel" src="smallm.png" alt="smallm">
            <input id="search" onclick="showAlert()" class="chnginput" type="text" name="suchparam" value="" placeholder="Suche" onkeyup="showhint(this.value)">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search posirel" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <select id="searcher"></select>
            <div id="srchbox"></div>
            <div id='target'></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but when I make the changes I only get random ASCII Characters
and the ajax.php is still empty

Comment: did you copy and run the above? (not as your final page though, just to test)

Comment: Yes but still it won't return the input in keyup.